# Selenium Chrome failed to create session in docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a flask application that receives a code (example http://localhost:8080/consult/[NUMBER]  ) then start a Selenium session to scrape a website and return a pdf. Locally it works smoothly but when I try to deploy inside a docker container and try to access the url that trigger the scrape function the following error occurs

```
web_1  |     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
web_1  |     super().__init__(
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
web_1  |     super().__init__(
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
web_1  |     self.start_session(capabilities)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
web_1  |     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
web_1  |     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
web_1  |     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
web_1  | selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
web_1  |   (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
web_1  |   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

My Dockerfile is the following

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3-distutils -y
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt install python-is-python3
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python3 get-pip.py

RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
COPY ./ ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV DOWNLOAD_DIR=file_downloads

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD ["main.py" ]
```

And the Selenium setup is the following

```py
    service = Service()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    #options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    #options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "download.default_directory": '/' + DOWNLOAD_DIR, # change default directory for downloads
    "download.prompt_for_download": False, # to auto download the file
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True # it will not show PDF directly in chrome
    })

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

The commented options are from related issues that I found online, but it was of no use.